# Pydev+Kivy - Empty __init__ files

Tags: python, initialization, pydev, kivy

I am using Eclipse and PyDev to develop for the Python library called Kivy.

I ran through the proper setup instructions, and developing and running from Eclipse works perfect.

However, when I, or more namley, my project-mates, try to run the file that contains the main method OUTSIDE of eclipse (via kivy cmd prompt), it comes up with the following error:

```
   File "C:\MyProject\code\main.py", line 8, in <module>
     from code import engine
 ImportError: cannot import name engine
```

The file code is basically:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from code import engine

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp.run()
```

I took a look in my project files. I have a bunch of **init**.py files

```
code/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    engine.py
    system1/
        __init__.py
        my_system.py
etc...
```

but all the **init**.py files are empty!
Am I supposed to construct them manually?
Eclipse must be doing it at some point, can I have PyDev do it automatically?

Comment: How should PyDev know which names to import, and which ones not to?

Comment: Based off the file structure, right? What packages and modules I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty `__init__.py` files are needed by Python (up to version 3.2) ideintify a directory as a Python package - and its contents as modules/sub-packages.

If you did not create them, PyDev created them for you - and they need not contain anything.

If your mates can't import `code.engine` asstated, it ismore likely the directory containing `code` itself is not part of Python's path (PYTHONPATH environment variable) - so it can't find from where do descend into the code package.

Comment: Or just run main.py from one directory below `code/`: `python code/main.py`, depending on how `engine.py` uses `system1`

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. @Scharron that worked ish. Some more errors follow, but I was running from the main directory, not the ../main, thanks!